# How to rotate the \ncarc commands in the following picture?

Tags: pstricks, pst-node

The official picture:

[image]

This is my code.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-7,-7)(7,7)
\psset{arrowsize=.3,arrowinset=.2}
\multido{\iA=0+60}{6}{\pnode(2.5;\iA){A\iA}}
\foreach \x/\y in {0/300,300/240,240/180,180/120,120/60,60/0}{%
    \psarcn[arcsep=.1]{->}(0,0){2.5}{\x}{\y}}
%%%%
\multido{\iA=15+60}{6}{\pnode(5;\iA){B\iA}}
\foreach \a/\b in {15/Thinking\\about methods,75/Choosing a topic,135/Writting up,195/Analysing data,255/Collecting data,315/Reading for\\research}{%
\rput[0](5;\a){\rnode{B\a}{\psDefBoxNodes{B'\a}{\small \sffamily \tabular[t]{l}\b\endtabular}}}}
%%%%
\psarcn[arcsep=.8]{->}(0,0){4.8}{15}{315}
\psarcn[arcsepA=1.75,arcsepB=2.4]{->}(0,0){4.8}{315}{255}
\psarcn[arcsepA=2.5,arcsepB=.5]{->}(0,0){5.1}{255}{195}
\psarcn[arcsepA=.75,arcsepB=.75]{->}(0,0){5.1}{195}{135}
\psarcn[arcsepA=.75,arcsepB=2.7]{->}(0,0){4.95}{135}{75}
\psarcn[arcsepA=2.6,arcsepB=.5]{->}(-.2,.2){5.1}{75}{15}
\ncarc[nodesepA=.1,arcangle=30]{->}{B75}{A60}
\ncarc[nodesepA=.01,arcangleA=30,arcangleB=27]{->}{B'135:Br}{A120}
\ncarc[nodesepA=.02,arcangleA=27,arcangleB=25]{->}{B195}{A180}
\ncarc[nodesepA=.15,arcangleA=27,arcangleB=25]{->}{B255}{A240}
\ncarc[nodesepA=.01,arcangleA=30,arcangleB=25]{->}{B'315:Cl}{A300}
\ncarc[nodesepA=.7,arcangleA=20,arcangleB=25]{->}{B'15:BC}{A0}
%%%%
%%%---- Several incompleted arcs ----%%%
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

P.S.: Certainly, I can also define `\pnodes...`, but that is *unintelligent* :)

Note: You can reproduce my code if you want to say several new things!

Done! (After reading user187802's code)

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}    
    \begin{pspicture}(-7,-7)(7,7)
    \psset{arrowsize=.25,arrowinset=.2,linewidth=1.2pt}%
    \degrees[6] 
    \multido{\iA=0+1,\rA=0.65+1}{6}{%
        \pnode(2.5;\iA){A\iA}
        \pnode(6.2;\rA){C\rA}       }
    \multido{\iA=0+-1,\rB=-1+-1}{6}{%
        \psarcn[arcsep=.1]{->}(0,0){2.5}{\iA}{\rB}
                                    }
%
\foreach \a/\b in {%
    0.25/Thinking\\about methods,
    1.25/Choosing a topic,
    2.25/Writting up,
    3.25/Analysing data,
    4.25/Collecting data,
    5.25/Reading for\\research}{%
    \rput[0](5;\a){%
        \rnode{B\a}{%
            \psDefBoxNodes{B'\a}{\small \sffamily \tabular[t]{l}\b\endtabular}}}}
        % Lệnh \psDefBoxNodes thì xem trong pst-node
    %%%%
    \psset{arcangle=0.4}%
    \psarcn[arcsep=.8]{->}(0,0){4.8}{0.25}{5.25}
    \psarcn[arcsepA=1.75,arcsepB=2.4]{->}(0,0){4.8}{5.25}{4.25}
    \psarcn[arcsepA=2.5,arcsepB=.5]{->}(0,0){5.1}{4.25}{3.25}
    \psarcn[arcsepA=.75,arcsepB=.75]{->}(0,0){5.1}{3.25}{2.25}
    \psarcn[arcsepA=.75,arcsepB=2.7]{->}(0,0){4.95}{2.25}{1.25}
    \psarcn[arcsepA=1.75,arcsepB=.4]{->}(-.3,.3){5.1}{1.15}{0.25}
    %%%
    \ncarc[nodesepA=.1]{->}{B1.25}{A1}
    \ncarc{->}{B'2.25:Br}{A2}
    \ncarc[arcangle=0.5]{->}{B3.25}{A3}
    \ncarc[nodesepA=.15]{->}{B4.25}{A4}
    \ncarc[arcangle=.5]{->}{B'5.25:Cl}{A5}
    \ncarc[nodesepA=.7]{->}{B'0.25:BC}{A0}
    %%%%
    \ncarc[arcangle=0.4]{->}{C0.65}{B'0.25:tC}
    \ncarc[nodesepA=.5]{->}{C1.65}{B'1.25:tC}
    \ncarc[arcangle=0.4]{->}{C2.65}{B'2.25:bl}
    \ncarc[arcangle=0.5]{->}{C3.65}{B3.25}
    \ncarc[arcangle=0.4]{->}{C4.65}{B'4.25:bC}
    \ncarc[arcangle=0.3]{->}{C5.65}{B'5.25:Cr}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: chishijimotoji 3?

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity God Must Be Crazy? ;-)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat marmot? :-)

Comment: Don't judge me by display name! :-)

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer Hello, for a long time, :-). `After all`, you are the first person to see my first package.  https://github.com/justonly011298/psteuclasy-ver-0.5 . I hope you'll come back.

Comment: @justonly: Very good!

Comment: OK......................................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-7,-7)(7,7)
\psset{arrowsize=.25,arrowinset=.2}%
\degrees[6]\sffamily
\multido{\iA=0+1,\rA=0.6+1.0}{6}{\pnode(2.5;\iA){A\iA}\pnode(6;\rA){C\iA}}
\multido{\iA=0+1,\rB=0.95+1.00}{6}{\psarc{<-}(0,0){2.5}{\iA}{\rB}}
%
\rput(5;0.25){\rnode{B0}{\shortstack{Thinking\\about methods}}}
\rput(5;1.25){\rnode{B1}{Choosing a topic}}
\rput(5;2.25){\rnode{B2}{Writing up}}
\rput(5;3.25){\rnode{B3}{Analysing data}}
\rput(5;4.25){\rnode{B4}{Collecting data}}
\rput(5;5.25){\rnode{B5}{\shortstack{Reading for\\research}}}
%%%%
\psset{arcangle=0.5}%
\psarcn[arcsep=.8]{->}(0,0){4.8}{0.25}{5.25}
\psarcn[arcsepA=1.75,arcsepB=2.4]{->}(0,0){4.8}{5.25}{4.25}
\psarcn[arcsepA=2.5,arcsepB=.5]{->}(0,0){5.1}{4.25}{3.25}
\psarcn[arcsepA=.75,arcsepB=.75]{->}(0,0){5.1}{3.25}{2.25}
\psarcn[arcsepA=.75,arcsepB=2.7]{->}(0,0){4.95}{2.25}{1.25}
\psarcn[arcsepA=2.6,arcsepB=.5]{->}(-.2,.2){5.1}{1.15}{0.25}
\multido{\iA=0+1}{6}{\ncarc[nodesepA=.05]{->}{B\iA}{A\iA}%
                     \ncarc[nodesepB=.1]{->}{C\iA}{B\iA}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can we do it without using `\pnode`?

Comment: sure, use simply the angles instead of the nodes.

Comment: Firstly, I think about `\rput` or `\uput` with the option `rotate`, but it doesn't work.